# java: Why does frame get the event of a component

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have a JFrame, which contains just a JPanel.
I add an mouse event to the JPanel.

But the whole JFrame gets the same mouse event.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestSwing extends JPanel {

      public TestSwing() {
          super.setSize(20, 20);
          addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
              public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
                System.out.println(me); 
              } 
            }); 

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestSwing());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```

I set the size of the JPanel `(20, 20)`, but no matter where I click, the mouse event will always be triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding that JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane, a component that uses BorderLayout, a layout which does not respect size or even for the most part preferred size, and so the JPanel will fill the entire JFrame's contentPane. Give the contentPane a FlowLayout and set the JPanel's preferred size and you'll see a difference. In the future, give the JPanel a Border to see its boundaries. This will make debugging this easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't tell it otherwise, your JFrame will have [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) like this:

[image]

Now if you furthermore don't tell your Panel where to go, it wil go into `CENTER` and thus be resized to fill whole content area.

For checking `MouseEvent` on only one `JPanel` I suggest you add another JPanel (maybe with different background?) to other area:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new TestSwing(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel left = new JPanel();
left.setBackground(Color.red);
frame.getContentPane().add(left, BorderLayout.LEFT);
```

Size set by `setSize()` is only valid until it's recalculated based on Layout and other properties.